# I have epson thermal printer model M129H. How to get the status of the printer ? like its on or not and paper roll is finished etc

Tags: c#, .net, printing, status, epson

I have epson thermal printer model M129H. How to get the status of the printer in my c# application ? The status includes:

1. Printer is on or off
2. Paper roll is finished
3. Error in printing
4. Paper roll fitter is open

etc.

Comment: i have no idea where to start from !

Answer (score 1):

Coding printer status from scratch is considerably difficult to do perfectly. Most printer manufacturers should have an API available to do it. I would suggest searching if Epson offers such an API.

For reference, you should look at the SDK these guys provide: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

Just take note that the Star SDK doesn't work for Epson printers because status and printer commands vary between printer manufacturers. However, I used Star's API/SDK for my own project and was done quicker than I thought. Good luck.